# Why the plane is not black?

Tags: unity, c#

[image: Plane]

I created a new material and changed the material colors to make it black:
R,G,B all value is 0 and A value is 255

The shader on the Plane is: Legacy Shaders/Transparent/Diffuse

But the Plane seems to be transparent.

The main goal is put a plane in front of the camera the FPSCamera and then using a script to fade in/out the alpha color.

Comment: Could you be looking at the back face? What's it look like from the other side?

Comment: @DMGregory The problem was that I was trying to change on the Scale the Y value to be positive like 1 or 4 or 5 and it didn't change anything. I had to change it to be negative. Once changed it to -0.02 or more it's showing the black color on the plane.

Comment: @BenziAvrumi A plane can't really scale on the Y axis, as it does not have "depth". If you scale Y to a negative value, the faces of the plane flip, so when you look at the front of the plane, you are actually looking at its back face.  you were simply looking at the place from its back side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to use the plane as a screen in front of the player instead use a UI pannel. They are easyer to manage, less likely to lag and more efficient as they don't take place in the 3D world.